# asp.net design where front end that can be easily swapped out or changed?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

whats a preferred pattern for designing a web application using asp.net where the UI can be easily modified or totally swapped out for another ui?

I dont mean using CSS to change the lipstick on the app, but if i was to use agile development to produce proof of concepts that i can re-use moving forward with application development... i want to prevent, or limit as much as i can, the possibility that a  change in the requirements that makes modifications to the UI will derail the development efforts put in up till then.

i was planing a service bases solution similar to SOA but wanted to vet my idea and check to see if i was missing anything that may suit this project better?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC would seem to fit your broad requirements.
http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: ASP.NET MVC makes it easier to create your unit tests as well.  This will help keep your stable layers stable, while you swap out views, etc.  Also mocking is easier so sample data for POCs is easier to apply.

Answer (score 1):

A service-based solution will mostly help you if you have a system that is consumed by multiple clients, which need to share common data or functionality.  Otherwise, I don't see its benefit to you as it pertains to the question.

You'll probably want to leverage user controls and different classes that resolve different business objectives.  Look into **separation of concerns** design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with DaveRead (I don't really trust unripe MS technologies, and MVC is still very new and not mature, in my view), and with Kon, in the sense that SOA solution is not just for multiple clients, but in my opinion it's a viable solution to (almost) any application.
but Kon rightly mentioned separation of concerns, which, if implemented correctly, should achieve just what you need.
A good rule of thumb is- when designing / coding your back-end layers, ask yourself: If I made a so-and-so change to the UI- would I have to change my back-end?
the answer, of course, should always be 'No'
good luck.

Comment: The MVC pattern is over 30 years old, but I see your point re: Microsoft's implementation

Comment: @sJohnny, I won't argue "viable" but I would not suggest SOA to be the best solution in many cases and have seen it misused often.  You have to realize that with SOA come additional layers of abstraction and performance (payload overhead).  Why do something in 3 steps if it can be done in 2?  It is also often (but not always) detrimental to maintainability.

Comment: @Dave: obviously I wasn't talking about MVC as a DP, but as a MS technology (damn you, MS, for taking advantage of well-known phrases for your own evil purposes!)  
@Kon: agreed. although I like the flexibility it gives you, and I feel it makes up for the extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I am a strong believer in [DataBinding](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_databinding.asp). It will allow you to keep the UI separated from the underlying logic and data. Changing the UI or Logic, or Data can be done with a minimum impact in the overall coherence of your website / application.
[image]
This image shows how Source and UI elements are seen as two separate blocks, and the Binding is the communication between them.